# Spacecraft acceleration - How fast could one possibly go without disintegrating?

Tags: material-science, space

Assuming we had a spacecraft that could accelerate up to 10% of the speed of light, what speed could be realistically reached without breaking its structure given current material science? Space debris can be ignored for this question.

Comment: When you're moving in a vacuum, speed doesn't matter. The only thing that could cause damage is acceleration, and even then only if different parts of your spacecraft were accelerating at different rates.

Comment: @probably_someone Well you'd have to accelerate quite a bit to reach such speed (within a reasonable amount of time for the sake of practical use).  Is the acceleration that even in current rocket and probes?

Comment: The final speed doesn't really have much to do with the acceleration. Given enough time, you could accelerate a spacecraft to $0.1c$ with a very tiny force.

Comment: @probably_someone true, hence my comment about a reasonable time frame for space travel. What time frame where you thinking about (days, months, years)?

Comment: The time frame depends on the maximum acceleration you're able to apply without causing damage to your ship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acceleration is very different from speed.  Yes, acceleration can cause stresses.  But your vehicle can get to any given speed with anything from a very low acceleration (like 1 km/hour per second) to a very high acceleration (like a million km/hour per second).  In the first case it takes one second to reach 1 km/hr.  In the second case it takes one microsecond to reach 1 km/hr.  As long as the acceleration is kept relatively low, the vehicle can just keep accelerating without damage until it reaches any speed you want.

Comment: The real structural problem would be to stack enough fuel. Thinking of rocket equation.

Answer (score 1):

For reaching a final speed of 10% of the speed of light, the above answers are completely correct. Speed doesn't matter, acceleration does, and even then, acceleration only matters when different parts of your ship are accelerating at different rates.

But this is only true up to a (very hard-to-reach) point, due to the existence of the Cosmic Microwave Background (CMB). It turns out that the faster you go, the more likely it is that the protons in your ship undergo the following reactions with CMB photons:

$$p+\gamma\to\Delta^+\to p+\pi^0$$

$$p+\gamma\to\Delta^+\to n+\pi^+$$

Once these reactions start to happen, the Cosmic Microwave Background itself begins to destroy your ship. It turns out that the threshold energy for these interactions to proceed is on the order of $10^{20}$ eV per proton (this is a well-known limit in cosmic-ray physics called the GZK cutoff). Assuming your ship is on the order of a few hundred kg, corresponding to something on the order of $10^{28}$ protons, in order for this to happen, your ship would have to have a kinetic energy of $10^{48}$ eV, which translates to $10^{29}$ J. This is obviously an impractical amount of energy (i.e. you would have to annihilate roughly $10^{12}$ kg of matter and antimatter to get yourself to that speed, which is roughly equivalent to the mass of all the fish on Earth), and would require you to have a speed so close to $c$ that an outside observer would scarcely be able to tell the difference, but it does set an upper limit on the kinetic energy of your ship if we assume that the CMB exists.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote, but this is really interesting.

Comment: Of course, in any realistic scenario, there would also be micrometeoroids and associated other space dust that would kill you long before you reach this limit, so it's not at all a practical bound. I just thought it was interesting that even in a debris-free scenario, your total energy is limited.

Comment: The spaceship will burn and evaporate long before.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're asking if speed, alone, is enough to cause a vehicle to disintegrate.

The immediate answer is that, in a vacuum, speed is irrelevant.  A vehicle traveling at 99% of the speed of light will not experience any stresses at all due to its speed.

The faster the vehicle moves relative to the surrounding stars, the more cosmic rays and micrometeorites it will encounter per second, just as a car driving through a rain storm will hit more raindrops per second than a stationary car.  But a vehicle with the mass of a Tesla would hardly notice the effects, even if it kept flying through the cosmos for a million years at near-lightspeed.

Comment: Wouldn't accelerating to that speed cause a lot of stress on it's structure? Sure once at that speed it likely wouldn't matter unless it collides with particles/micrometeorites.

Comment: Accelerating at a low rate causes very little stress.  Accelerating at a low rate for a very long time will build up very high speed.